# How do I properly cancel Parallel.Foreach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, parallel-processing

I've got code which looks something like this:

```
Parallel.Foreach(ItemSource(),(item)=>DoSomething(item));
```

`ItemSource()` produces an infinite stream of items.

I want the loop to exit once some condition has been met, and I'd rather do it without throwing an exception in DoSomething (I consider this approach a bad programming style).

Ideally, there would be something like cancellationToken. I would call cancellationToken.Activate() in one or more threads, after which parallel.foreach would stop creating new threads and after the last thread has exited, the function would return.

Is this possible to do in c#  with Parallel.ForEach, or should I use threads insteag?

**UPDATE** 
Here's how [microsoft suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256691.aspx) I do it:

```
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(nums, po, (num) =>
            {
                double d = Math.Sqrt(num);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} on {1}", d, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                po.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

I don't like this approach, because it involves throwing exception inside the delegate.

Comment: You don't have to throw an exception.  You can just check the `CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested` property and return from the method in any way you want.

Comment: The benefit of throwing the exception is that you have the opportunity to know as the caller of the task whether it was cancelled.  It makes the most sense in the scope of tasks which return a value.  For example, if you run a task to return a string... how do you know if there was an error or cancellation?  You could return null but what if null is a valid successful result for this task?  Exceptions have the same usefulness in tasks as they do in regular methods.

Comment: @TrevorElliott as far as I know, throwing an exception is an inherently slow operation

Comment: What's worse, having slightly slower code or having an uncaught bug in your code?

Comment: @ArsenZahray It's all relative.  The costs of throwing and catching an exception are pretty expensive compared to things like simple pointer manipulation, memory access, simple arithmetic, etc.  But compared to the costs of creating a new thread, synchronizing access between multiple threads, the context switches going on, etc. the exception is not going to be a significant portion of the execution time of a method like this.  It's important to consider "cost" statements like that in context.

Comment: So, you've seen how it's suggested this be done properly.  What are you asking?  If you want to know how this *should* be done, you've just shown an example.  That's how it should be done.  If you don't like it, that's fine, you're more than welcome to do things your own way.  The standard practices aren't right for everyone.  But what are you asking here?

Answer (score 22):

In Parallel.ForEach there is an option to create a ParallelLoopState this state allows you to break the loop:

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Constants.MaxParallelProcesses;
var drc = Companies.AsEnumerable();

Parallel.ForEach(drc, po, (drcCompany, loopState) =>
{
    //do stuff here
    if(YourBreakCondition) loopState.Break();
}
```

Check the ParallelLoopState here http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.aspx

Comment: For completeness... an alternative to Break is the Stop method.

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, because `Parallel.For()`/`Parallel.ForEach()` already does that internally.
That [Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-cancel-a-parallel-for-or-foreach-loop) will be updated soon - [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/27419)